# Using javac to mimic Eclipse compilation structure

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to free myself of dependence on IDEs and using standard text editors (Emacs to be specific). However, one thing I was certainly a fan of was how Eclipse organized projects, mainly into src/ and bin/ directories where the structures were identical, except for every file X.java found in src/, there would be X.class in bin/

What would be the javac command to execute that would allow me this structure?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I suggest looking at Maven (or Gradle) instead. These are purpose-built tools that handle compilation, dependencies, packaging, and more.

Comment: In addition to the above, you may find [jdee](http://jdee.sourceforge.net/) helpful.